# IE8 doesn't float nicely

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

The site in question is [here](http://aline-senn.ichbinadrian.ch/).

All Browser except ie7 and ie8 display the page proper. Those two don't float the two main elements `nav#navigation` and `section#content`. I already tried using `html5_shiv`.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said html5 shiv didn't work, but it should. Regardless, you could manually apply the fix yourself. In the `<head>`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('nav');
document.createElement('section');
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('aside');
document.createElement('footer');
document.createElement('hgroup');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

And the CSS file:

```
header, nav, section, article, aside, footer, hgroup {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well. The css part is fixed through eric meyers css reset. And I copied your code into the template again. Still doesn't float nicely in ie8. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Now it works. Put it into the head was the final step. Thanks alot.